# How to Install Ubuntu on Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

So I've been looking around for an answer, and I can't seem to find anything resolved in terms of the problem I'm having. Here's the deal, I have an ASUS laptop that has Windows 8 preinstalled on it. It has 6 GB of ram with a 64-bit operating system. The only problem is that I'm sick and tired of Windows 8. I was hoping I might be able to install Ubuntu, but I've heard it's almost impossible. I've read that it can be done though... The only problem I'm having is *how* I might be able to do so. If anyone could give me a step-by-step guide or a link somewhere that is VERY helpful, especially for a first-timer like myself, I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the installation guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall